# POST calls return 404 In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am creating signup Api 1st call is **GET** and 2nd is **POST** call.
When I make GET[POSTMAN] call I get proper response from the controller but when I make POST it returns 404.

### web.php

```
// sign up api

Route::get('signup','Api\RegistrationController@createUser');
Route::post('/signup','Api\RegistrationController@storeUser');
```

### RegistrationController.php

```
public function createUser(){
    return "Get : Sign up";
}

public function storeUser() {
    // validate the form
    $this->validate(request(),[
        'firstname' => 'required',
        'lastname' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    // create and save the user
    $user = Register::create(request(['firstname', 'lastename', 'email', 'password']));

    return "Registration complete";
}
```

I am using laravel 5.4.  When route url is kept same (i.e signup) then GET method executes for POST call, when route url  different it returns 404.

[Screenshot : its a POST call but GET route executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SThpC.png)

Comment: Run `php artisan route:list`...let's see what you've got.

Comment: I checked it. its proper.
1. | GET|HEAD                               | signup                                               |                                 | App\Http\Controllers\Api\RegistrationController@createUser 

2. |        | POST                                   | signup                                               |                                 | App\Http\Controllers\Api\RegistrationController@storeUser

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let me know:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function storeUser(Request $request) {
// validate the form

$this->validate($request,[
  'firstname' => 'required',
  'lastname' => 'required',
  'email' => 'required',
  'password' => 'required'
]);

 // create and save the user

  $user = Register::create($request->all());

  return "Registration complete";
}
```

**Note:** When developing api's always define Api routes in api.php file.

Comment: @rahuldas post the screen shot of your Api request you making via postman.

Comment: @rahuldas Change this Route::post('/signup','Api\RegistrationController@storeUser'); to Route::post('register','Api\RegistrationController@storeUser'); and now try

Comment: tried this as well but nothing. in fact post calls are not working be it signup or some other.

Comment: are you sending headers as accept: application/json and content-type: application/json

Comment: define the same routes in api.php file and then when you make any request from postman just add /api before orignal route e.g 127.0.0.1:8000/api/signup

Answer (score 0):

**Write All your API Routes in api.php file instead of web.php**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
public function storeUser(Request $request) {

// first check whether your request is coming here or not
// if not coming
// it is the issue of Routing   

dd('coming..');
//if it prints coming then comment this dd

$this->validate($request,[
 'firstname' => 'required',
 'lastname' => 'required',
 'email' => 'required',
 'password' => 'required'
]);

   $user = Register::create($request->all());
}
```

Comment: write your Api routes in api.php instead of web.php

Comment: added those routes in api.php still no. now it stoped working for GET call as well.

Comment: share your team viewer ID & password

Comment: It is too late but still, The Answer is you have to use /api prefix before all the routes.

like-

BASE_URL/api/signup

Answer (score 0):

For api requests , you should not use a custom Http Request that Extends FormRequest but instead
`use Illuminate\Http\Request;`